# matplotlib and numpy - histogram bar color and normalization

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, histogram2d

So I have 2 problems:

1- I have a 2D histogram w/ 1D histograms along the x & y axes. These histograms total up their respective x and y values, while the main histogram totals the values in logarithmic x-y bins. The code is below. I've used pcolormesh to generate the 2D histogram... and I've generated a color bar in the range vmin=1, vmax=14 ... I make these constant since I'm generating a set of these plots over a wide data range -- and I want the colors to be consistent across them.

I also want to color the 1D histogram bars according to the same normalization. I've setup a function to do the mapping, but it is stubbornly linear -- even tho I specify LogNorm for the mapping.

I've attached a couple plots that show what I think is a linear scale for the 1D histograms. Look at x-axis histogram values around 10^4 (or 10^6)... They are colored at the 1/2 way point in the color bar, not at the log scale point.

What am I doing wrong?

2- I also want to eventually normalize the 1D histograms by the bin width (xrange or yrange). However, I don't think I can do it directly in the matplotlib.hist. Maybe I should use np hist, but then I don't know how to do a matplotlib.bar plot with log scale and colored bars (again, mapping the colors I use for the 2D hist).

Here's the code:

```
#
# 20 Oct 2015
# Rick Sarmento
#
# Purpose:
#  Reads star particle data and creates phase plots
#  Place histograms of x and y axis along axes
#  Uses pcolormesh norm=LogNorm(vmin=1,vmax=8)
#
# Method:
#  Main plot uses np.hist2d then takes log of result
#
# Revision history
#

# ##########################################################
# Generate colors for histogram bars based on height
# This is not right! 
# ##########################################################
def colorHistOnHeight(N, patches):
    # we need to normalize the data to 0..1 for the full
    # range of the colormap
    print("N max: %.2lf"%N.max())
    fracs = np.log10(N.astype(float))/9.0 # normalize colors to the top of our scale
    print("fracs max: %.2lf"%fracs.max())
    norm = mpl.colors.LogNorm(2.0, 9.0)
    # NOTE this color mapping is different from the one below.
    for thisfrac, thispatch in zip(fracs, patches):
        color = mpl.cm.jet(thisfrac)
        thispatch.set_facecolor(color)

    return

# ##########################################################
# Generate a combo contour/density plot
# ##########################################################
def genDensityPlot(x, y, mass, pf, z, filename, xaxislabel):
    """

    :rtype : none
    """
    nullfmt = NullFormatter()

    # Plot location and size
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
    ax2dhist = plt.axes(rect_2dhist)
    axHistx = plt.axes(rect_histx)
    axHisty = plt.axes(rect_histy)

    # Fix any "log10(0)" points...
    x[x == np.inf] = 0.0
    y[y == np.inf] = 0.0
    y[y > 1.0] = 1.0 # Fix any minor numerical errors that could result in y>1

    # Bin data in log-space
    xrange = np.logspace(minX,maxX,xbins)
    yrange = np.logspace(minY,maxY,ybins)
    # Note axis order: y then x
    # H is the binned data... counts normalized by star particle mass
    # TODO -- if we're looking at x = log Z, don't weight by mass * f_p... just mass!
    H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, weights=mass * (1.0 - pf), # We have log bins, so we take 
                                        bins=(yrange,xrange))

    # Use the bins to find the extent of our plot
    extent = [yedges[0], yedges[-1], xedges[0], xedges[-1]]

    # levels = (5, 4, 3) # Needed for contours only... 

    X,Y=np.meshgrid(xrange,yrange) # Create a mess over our range of bins

    # Take log of the bin data
    H = np.log10(H)
    masked_array = np.ma.array(H, mask=np.isnan(H))  # mask out all nan, i.e. log10(0.0)

    # Fix colors -- white for values of 1.0. 
    cmap = copy.copy(mpl.cm.jet)
    cmap.set_bad('w', 1.)  # w is color, for values of 1.0

    # Create a plot of the binned
    cax = (ax2dhist.pcolormesh(X,Y,masked_array, cmap=cmap, norm=LogNorm(vmin=1,vmax=8)))
    print("Normalized H max %.2lf"%masked_array.max())

    # Setup the color bar
    cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[1, 2, 4, 6, 8])
    cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['1', '2', '4', '6', '8'], size=24)
    cbar.set_label('$log\, M_{sp, pol,\odot}$', size=30)

    ax2dhist.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=22)
    ax2dhist.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=22)
    ax2dhist.set_xlabel(xaxislabel, size=30)
    ax2dhist.set_ylabel('$log\, Z_{pri}/Z$', size=30)

    ax2dhist.set_xlim([10**minX,10**maxX])
    ax2dhist.set_ylim([10**minY,10**maxY])
    ax2dhist.set_xscale('log')
    ax2dhist.set_yscale('log')
    ax2dhist.grid(color='0.75', linestyle=':', linewidth=2)

    # Generate the xy axes histograms
    ylims = ax2dhist.get_ylim()
    xlims = ax2dhist.get_xlim()

    ##########################################################
    # Create the axes histograms
    ##########################################################
    # Note that even with log=True, the array N is NOT log of the weighted counts
    # Eventually we want to normalize these value (in N) by binwidth and overall
    # simulation volume... but I don't know how to do that.
    N, bins, patches = axHistx.hist(x, bins=xrange, log=True, weights=mass * (1.0 - pf))
    axHistx.set_xscale("log")
    colorHistOnHeight(N, patches)
    N, bins, patches = axHisty.hist(y, bins=yrange, log=True, weights=mass * (1.0 - pf),
                                    orientation='horizontal')
    axHisty.set_yscale('log')
    colorHistOnHeight(N, patches)

    # Setup format of the histograms
    axHistx.set_xlim(ax2dhist.get_xlim())  # Match the x range on the horiz hist
    axHistx.set_ylim([100.0,10.0**9])       # Constant range for all histograms
    axHistx.tick_params(labelsize=22)
    axHistx.yaxis.set_ticks([1e2,1e4,1e6,1e8])
    axHistx.grid(color='0.75', linestyle=':', linewidth=2)

    axHisty.set_xlim([100.0,10.0**9])       # We're rotated, so x axis is the value
    axHisty.set_ylim([10**minY,10**maxY])  # Match the y range on the vert hist
    axHisty.tick_params(labelsize=22)
    axHisty.xaxis.set_ticks([1e2,1e4,1e6,1e8])
    axHisty.grid(color='0.75', linestyle=':', linewidth=2)

    # no labels
    axHistx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)
    axHisty.yaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)

    if z[0] == '0': z = z[1:]
    axHistx.set_title('z=' + z, size=40)

    plt.savefig(filename + "-z_" + z + ".png", dpi=fig.dpi)
    #    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig) # Release memory assoc'd with the plot
    return


# ##########################################################
# ##########################################################
##
## Main program
##
# ##########################################################
# ##########################################################
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import matplotlib.colors as colors # For the colored 1d histogram routine
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatterMathtext
import numpy as np
import copy as copy

files = [
    "18.00",
    "17.00",
    "16.00",
    "15.00",
    "14.00",
    "13.00",
    "12.00",
    "11.00",
    "10.00",
    "09.00",
    "08.50",
    "08.00",
    "07.50",
    "07.00",
    "06.50",
    "06.00",
    "05.50",
    "05.09"
]
# Plot parameters - global
left, width = 0.1, 0.63
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.63
bottom_h = left_h = left + width + 0.01

xbins = ybins = 100

rect_2dhist = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect_histx = [left, bottom_h, width, 0.15]
rect_histy = [left_h, bottom, 0.2, height]

prefix = "./"
# prefix="20Sep-BIG/"
for indx, z in enumerate(files):
    spZ = np.loadtxt(prefix + "spZ_" + z + ".txt", skiprows=1)
    spPZ = np.loadtxt(prefix + "spPZ_" + z + ".txt", skiprows=1)
    spPF = np.loadtxt(prefix + "spPPF_" + z + ".txt", skiprows=1)
    spMass = np.loadtxt(prefix + "spMass_" + z + ".txt", skiprows=1)

    print ("Generating phase diagram for z=%s" % z)
    minY = -4.0
    maxY = 0.5
    minX = -8.0
    maxX = 0.5
    genDensityPlot(spZ, spPZ / spZ, spMass, spPF, z,
                   "Z_PMassZ-MassHistLogNorm", "$log\, Z_{\odot}$")
    minX = -5.0
    genDensityPlot((spZ) / (1.0 - spPF), spPZ / spZ, spMass, spPF, z,
                   "Z_PMassZ1-PGF-MassHistLogNorm", "$log\, Z_{\odot}/f_{pol}$")
```

Here are a couple plots showing the problem with the coloring of the 1D axis histograms

[image: Plot 1]

[image: Plot 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0) Your code is very nicely (and helpfully!) documented, but it would be very helpful for you to trim down to a ***minimal*** working example.
1) the `fracs` array in `colorHistOnHeight` does not include the lower bound of 1e2.
2) The bounds of your different `LogNorm` colormaps are changing throughout your code (e.g. [1,8] vs. [2,9]).  Set these parameters to variables, and pass those variables as needed.
3) Create a scalar mappable object [`matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable`](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable) object to convert a scalar value directly into a color using the `to_rgba` method.

Hope one of those helps!

Comment: Yes.  Something like, `(log10(N)-2.0)/9.0`

Comment: Ah thanks... I just realized I create norm, but don't use it!  1) Hum... true. I guess I'm current mapping the bottom of my range to the interval 2->9.  2) That is a typo -- I do have the ranges set the same.  3) I'll look into that.  Thanks!!

Comment: I can't make sense of how to use the ScalarMappable... If you could point me at an example I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Hum... got the ScalarMappable object created, but I thought the frac would already be a scalar -- nope. Gotta figure out how to convert the _thisfrac_ objects into a scalar value in the log-range I want to map the colors to....

Comment: @earnric sorry to leave you hanging, but I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to use the above suggestion: `matplotlib.sm.ScalarMappable`. This does it! The mapping matches my colorbar scale.

```
# ##########################################################
# Generate colors for histogram bars based on height
# Method:
#  Take log of the histogram values (weighted counts)..
#  Create a LogNorm mapping between 1->9
#  Use the norm to map scalar values between 1 & 9 to rgb
# ##########################################################
def colorHistOnHeight(N, patches):
    cleanN = np.ma.masked_where(N == 0.0, N)
    fracs  = np.log10(cleanN) # normalize colors to the top of our scale
    norm   = mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=1.0, vmax=9.0)
    sm     = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=mpl.cm.jet)
    sm.set_clim([1.0,9.0])
    for thisfrac, thispatch in zip(fracs, patches):
        color = sm.to_rgba(thisfrac)
        thispatch.set_facecolor(color)
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's how I was able to normalize the matplotlib hist by the logarithmic bin width (and the volume of my simulation -- a scalar value). Someone please check my solution however.

```
yrange = np.logspace(minY,maxY,ybins)
N, bins, patches = axHisty.hist(y, bins=yrange, log=True, weights=mass * (1.0 - pf))

widths = np.diff(bins)
for item,dbx in zip(patches,widths):
    item.set_height(item.get_height()/dbx/cmvol)
```

I normalize the heights of the histogram rectangles by the bin width (dbx) and the comoving volume of my simulation (cmvol). I think this does it!

[image: Normalized plot]